# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextName.Text != "" && TextPass.Text != "" && TextRePass.Text != "" && TextAddr.Text != "" && TextPhn.Text != "")
    {
        SqlConnection i = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Study materials\Mobile Shop\App_Data\;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        i.Open();
        string q = "insert into Register values ('" + TextName.Text + "','" + TextRePass.Text + "','" + TextAddr.Text + "','" + TextPhn.Text + "','" + Label1.Text + "','" + Label2.Text + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, i);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label3.Text = "DETAILS ENTERED SUCCESSFULLY IN THE DATABASE!!";
    }
    else
    {
        Label4.Text = "ALL FIELDS ARE MANDATORY";
    }
}
```

I having a error here:

```
i.Open();
```

Error is:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Study materials\Mobile Shop\App_Data\ failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Study materials\Mobile Shop\App_Data\ failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: your sql constring path is not pointing to any database file..(mdf)

Comment: This is the best way to open your database to any kind of sql injection

Answer (score 1):

You need a database name in the Connection String:

```
SqlConnection i = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Study materials\Mobile Shop\App_Data\<DB Name Here>;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
                                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```